# A '/' appears in the output of the sdiff command

Tags: bash, xubuntu

I am using sdiff command on ubuntu to test my code.

```
python main.py | sdiff - ans.txt
```

At this time, the output is as follows

```
>sequence1: frame1                      >sequence1: frame1
PSRAFWREEE EEEVGGGP*                    PSRAFWREEE EEEVGGGP*
>sequence1: frame2                      >sequence1: frame2
RAELSGERKR KRKWEAGP                     RAELSGERKR KRKWEAGP
>sequence1: frame3                      >sequence1: frame3
EQSFLERGRG RGSGRRAL                     EQSFLERGRG RGSGRRAL
>sequence1: frame-1                     >sequence1: frame-1
LGPASHFLFL FLSPESSAR                    LGPASHFLFL FLSPESSAR
>sequence1: frame-2                     >sequence1: frame-2
*GPPPTSSSS SSLQKALL                     *GPPPTSSSS SSLQKALL
>sequence1: frame-3                     >sequence1: frame-3
RARLPLPLPL PLSRKLCS                   / RARLPLPLPL PLSRKLCS
```

What does this `/` mean?
To me, the left and right outputs look the same.
So I don't know why the `/` is outputting

Answer (score 1):

It probably indicates that the second line is missing its terminating newline, ex.

```
$ sdiff <(printf 'foo bar\n') <(printf 'foo bar')
foo bar                               / foo bar
```

> ‘/’ The corresponding lines differ, and only the second line is
>   incomplete.
>
> Normally, an output line is incomplete if and only if the lines that
>   it contains are incomplete. See Incomplete Lines. However, when an
>   output line represents two differing lines, one might be incomplete
>   while the other is not. In this case, the output line is complete, but
>   its the gutter is marked ‘\’ if the first line is incomplete, ‘/’ if
>   the second line is.

See

- [Showing Differences Side by Side](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Side-by-Side.html)
- [Incomplete Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Incomplete-Lines.html#Incomplete-Lines)